# Computing Hochschild cohomology of an algebra in GAP

Tags: homology-cohomology, gap, quiver, hochschild-cohomology

I would like to calculate Hochschild cohomology of a path algebra of a quiver (modulo some relations) using GAP.

Creating the quiver and its path algebra modulo relations is explained in detail in the [QPA manual](https://folk.ntnu.no/oyvinso/QPA/manual.pdf).

After having defined an algebra $A$ I used

```
M := AlgebraAsModuleOverEnvelopingAlgebra(A);
```

to regard $A$ as a module over its enveloping algebra $A \otimes A^{\mathrm{op}}$.

There are a few steps left to calculate Hochschild cohomology:

1. find a projective resolution $P^\bullet$ of $M$,
2. take $\operatorname{Hom} (-, A)$ of the complex $P^\bullet$ (or rather its truncation?),
3. calculate the homology of the resulting complex.

For step 1, there are both `ProjectiveResolution` and `ProjectiveResolutionOfPathAlgebraModule`. Which would be preferable here?

Step 2 I don't know how to do in GAP.

(Step 3 should be `HomologyOfComplex(C,i);` where `C` is the output from step 2.)

Comment: For a package-specific question, it might be better to ask [QPA](https://folk.ntnu.no/oyvinso/QPA/) authors directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In QPA one can compute $Ext$-groups via the command `ExtOverAlgebra`.  Using the setup above with

```
M := AlgebraAsModuleOverEnvelopingAlgebra(A);
```

one can continue as follows:

```
HH1 := ExtOverAlgebra(M, M);
HH2 := ExtOverAlgebra(NthSyzygy(M, 1), M);
HH3 := ExtOverAlgebra(NthSyzygy(M, 2), M);
.......
HHn := ExtOverAlgebra(NthSyzygy(M, n - 1), M);
```

which computes the first, the second, the third, ..., the $n$-th Hochschild cohomology groups. The output from `ExtOverAlgebra` is a list of three elements, where the second entry is a list of basis vectors for the Ext-group as maps from the appropriate syzygy module to the extension module.  If one is also interested in algebra structure, the command `ExtAlgebraGenerators` computes generators for the Ext-algebra (not necessarily minimal) up to a prescribed degree. For example,

```
ExtAlgebraGenerators(M, 4);
```

I hope that this is helpful.

Best regards, The QPA-team.